# Weird block above TabBar in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

[image: Screenshot]

A weird block that is presented in all view controllers pushed from this root viewcontroller. What is that and how to get rid of it?

Comment: I would suggest editing the question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small, stand-alone example that manifests the problem. I suspect some incorrect/missing constraints, but it is impossible to diagnose on the basis of what has been provided thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncheck "Show toolbar" in the attributes section of the view in the question.